# Left-continuity of the supremum process

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X$ be a measurable process on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. My question is if the supremum

$$
Y_t=\sup_{s<t}X_s,
$$

is left continuous. It's important that $s<t$ is strict. I'm somehow not capable of deriving a proper proof. My thoughts were about showing, for $t_n\rightarrow t$
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\;\sup_{s<t_n} X_s= Y_t \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{t_n\leq s<t} X_s=0,
$$

and arguing that **if** there's a jump before $t$ such that the supremum would have a higher value, there's a $t_n$ before which the jump has taken place. Does this suffice?